# Corda 4.3 Enterprise Issue - 0 rows available

Tags: corda

Getting this error from node:

Can someone please shed some light on the issue and resolution?

Thank you!

```
2020-06-09 15:21:41,660 INFO n.c.n.s.s.StaffedFlowHospital [flow-worker] Flow error allowed to propagate
net.corda.core.node.services.StatesNotAvailableException: Attempted to reserve [CDDA501510A70B04133BAB2977891F74DDF377422C2F61F30DAD61EBDBD01B19(0), 2D64BB53971CC0DDCA307A23EF2E86A6211FFFEC8A8D443CBAB6755FB1508B6B(0), CB4AD5262750CD6DC7E33B057E73A3CAB61EBCF83E7232A803025A64F0C66F16(0), 9AA0489DFCEACC6B5E10603EA8FC0C93891395B9658B1E7A7E0CD793BF4BD01E(0), E8A5427BA1161885797F616319E278B88041FB3E25C68DF53EC4AA8FA665FE7E(0)] for afa31821-c37a-4f13-8fed-1a214f945ffc but only 0 rows available
       at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.softLockReserve(NodeVaultService.kt:535) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
        at cm.token.helpers.StateQueryUtility.searchForTokens(StateQueryUtility.kt:179) ~[?:?]
        at cm.token.flows.subFlows.ConsumeTokenFlow.call(ConsumeTokenFlow.kt:21) ~[?:?]
        at cm.token.flows.subFlows.ConsumeTokenFlow.call(ConsumeTokenFlow.kt:16) ~[?:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:334) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:326) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
        at cm.token.flows.TransferFlow.call(TransferFlow.kt:65) ~[?:?]
        at cm.token.flows.TransferFlow.call(TransferFlow.kt:26) ~[?:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:274) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:46) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.11_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.11_r3]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.11_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.11_r3]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.11_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.11_r3]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.11_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.11_r3]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_242]
2020-06-09 15:21:41,661 DEBUG c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection [flow-worker] HikariPool-1 - Executed rollback on connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@372f7bc due to dirty commit state on close().
2020-06-09 15:21:41,661 INFO n.c.n.s.s.StaffedFlowHospital [flow-worker] Flow [3cc9d3ac-857b-4556-b1b3-2dac96e03ece] admitted to hospital in state StateMachineState(checkpoint=Checkpoint(invocationContext=InvocationContext(origin=RPC(actor=Actor(id=Id(value=user1), serviceId=AuthServiceId(value=NODE_CONFIG), owningLegalIdentity=CN=Custodian1, OU=Custodian1, O=Cl
```

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

It looks like you ran into a soft locking error which occurs when "a node constructing transactions attempts to use the same input(s) simultaneously". https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/soft-locking.html

As the docs note this is important because only one of the two transactions which includes the same input state can be completed. The notary will reject the second transaction to complete as it is a double spend attempt.

If you want in depth information you can check the Corda open source code for the error message and see that this occurs during transaction assembly: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.4/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/vault/NodeVaultService.kt#L500

**Possible Resolution**

One common cause of soft locking conflicts is a flow being retried. If a flow is started with the same parameters twice then it is likely that the same input states will be selected again and result in this soft locking error.

By design Corda flow are intended to eventually complete so retrying flows as would be done in an standard web service is not a good design practice for Corda applications. If a flow is not completing then investigate the cause of the stuck flow and try to resolve that. If a flow must be retried if must first be killed https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/checkpoint-tooling.html

Comment: Your solution references version 4.4 .. we are running 4.3.  Does the same still apply?

Also, how do we resolve/fix this?  Currently all flow functionalities are just timing out on this node.

Comment: Yes this also applies to 4.3 as soft locking has been a part of Corda for a long time. I'll edit the answer to discuss possible resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Issue turned out to be two-fold:
1) an attempted use of duplicate keys in our postgresql database setup.
2) Flow retry attempt locked up the node so NO flows would run successfully.

Found this error in the postgres logs:

> 2020-06-09 20:39:15 UTC:172.30.63.181(44758):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5501]:ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_jj5rltk3d1ak3xi1d1oei0t4b"
>   2020-06-09 20:39:15 UTC:172.30.63.181(44758):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5501]:DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(cmsbi2@CUSTDN1) already exists.
>   2020-06-09 20:39:15 UTC:172.30.63.181(44758):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5501]:STATEMENT: insert into "CompanyHoldingIssuer".white_list_user (custodian_name, is_custodian, user_id, output_index, transaction_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
>   2020-06-09 20:39:15 UTC:172.30.63.181(44760):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5517]:ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_jj5rltk3d1ak3xi1d1oei0t4b"
>   2020-06-09 20:39:15 UTC:172.30.63.181(44760):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5517]:DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(Foundation@FOUNDTN) already exists.
>   2020-06-09 20:39:15 UTC:172.30.63.181(44760):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5517]:STATEMENT: insert into "CompanyHoldingIssuer".white_list_user (custodian_name, is_custodian, user_id, output_index, transaction_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
>   2020-06-09 20:39:16 UTC:172.30.63.181(44760):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5517]:ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_jj5rltk3d1ak3xi1d1oei0t4b"
>   2020-06-09 20:39:16 UTC:172.30.63.181(44760):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5517]:DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(cmsbi2@CUSTDN1) already exists.
>   2020-06-09 20:39:16 UTC:172.30.63.181(44760):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5517]:STATEMENT: insert into "CompanyHoldingIssuer".white_list_user (custodian_name, is_custodian, user_id, output_index, transaction_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
>   2020-06-09 20:39:16 UTC:172.30.63.181(44762):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5518]:ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_jj5rltk3d1ak3xi1d1oei0t4b"
>   2020-06-09 20:39:16 UTC:172.30.63.181(44762):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5518]:DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(Foundation@FOUNDTN) already exists.
>   2020-06-09 20:39:16 UTC:172.30.63.181(44762):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5518]:STATEMENT: insert into "CompanyHoldingIssuer".white_list_user (custodian_name, is_custodian, user_id, output_index, transaction_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
>   2020-06-09 20:39:17 UTC:172.30.63.181(44758):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5501]:ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_jj5rltk3d1ak3xi1d1oei0t4b"
>   2020-06-09 20:39:17 UTC:172.30.63.181(44758):qa2corda@corda_qa2:[5501]:DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(cmsbi2@CUSTDN1) already exists.

Solution was to restart ALL nodes in the environment.  Seems a third party node was the cause as restarting the node in question did not resolve.